# how to initialize array in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am completely new in swift and iOS developing. 
I want to initialize this array

I defined the array like this when my class starts

```
 var i = 0
 var ArrayTitle = [NSString]()
```

and then I need to initialize it in one of the functions like this

```
 let ArrayTitl[i] = "text"
```

and I checked it even like this but the error is same

```
let ArrayTitl[0] = "text"
```

but it has this Error 
`Cannot assign to immutable expression of type '[Int]'`

Appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: There are so many issues, please read [A Swift Tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-ID1)

Comment: Welcome to Swift! Start off by reading the [language guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html). It will explain basics such as this. 

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID109

Comment: Also, you wouldn't ever use "let" in this way. Let is used to define a variable - which MAY include an assignment but doesn't have to. But, once it is defined (as your array is), you wouldn't use a let.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using a dynamic array so you need to append the value.

Here's a small exemple:

```
var arrayTitle = [String]()

arrayTitle.append("text")

print(arrayTitle[0]);
```

Comment: **Do not** suggest `NSString` and variable names starting with capital letters in Swift by keeping the bad habits

Comment: I just copied the code above, but yes, I will correct it!